# Vue.js data table only showing data in first column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to iterate through an object, pulled from database using axios. I am able to make the object show up in my data table, but i am unable to make it break the data to the specified columns

first snippet is the parent component. the tr and td for the actual list i broke out to a separate component but that may need to be fixed.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<router-link to="/add" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float- 
right">AddClient</router-link>
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead> 
<client-info></client-info>      
</table>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import ClientInfo from '@/components/clientslistexperience/ClientInfo'


export default {
name: 'ClientsList',
components: {
ClientInfo
},
methods: {

},

}
</script>

enter code here
```

next is the component iterating through the data to be show in the table

```
<template>
<div class="client-info">
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(client, index) in clients"  v-bind:key="index"  
 :client="client">
            <th scope="row">{{ client.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

import { mapState } from 'vuex'

```
  export default {
name: 'client-info',
props: {
    id: Array,
    type: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phone: Number, 
},
computed: {
    ...mapState ([
        'clients'
    ])
},
created() {
this.$store.dispatch('retrieveClients')
}

}
</script>
enter code here
```

last is the vuex store where axios request is being made. now i know using the vuex for smaller projects is over kill but im intending for this to become rather large so this is the method ive chosen. any help would be awesome! Thanks.

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Vuex from 'vuex'
  import axios from 'axios'

   Vue.use(Vuex)
   axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://client-api.test/api'

   export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
    clients: []
   },
   mutations: {
    retrieveClients(state, clients) {
      state.clients = clients
    },
   },
   actions: {
    retrieveClients(context) {
      axios.get('/clients')
      .then(response => {
        // console.log(response)
        context.commit('retrieveClients', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
    }
    })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORjSK.png)

Comment: Have you tried removing the empty table header (`<th>`) from the `thead` of your `table`, because you have 6 columns defined in the header section of your table, but only 5 cells defined in the body of your table?

Comment: Remove `div class="client-info">` from above `tbody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you need to remove the `div` root element in your `ClientInfo.vue` component. 
Replace the `div` by `tbody` and it solve your problem ;)

```
<template>
      <tbody class="client-info">
        <tr v-for="(client, index) in clients"  
          :key="index">
              <td>{{ client.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ client.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ client.type }}</td>
              <td>{{ client.email }}</td>
              <td>{{ client.phone }}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</template>
```

Full demo here > https://codesandbox.io/s/v8vw0z89r7

Comment: That worked. You are my hero Lol Thanks! just out of curiosity. i notice your using "const" and then exporting the new Vue after. is that a better way to format the code or does it really matter?

Comment: Glad I've helped you TJ ! Using "const" is ES6+ feature (a value can't be reassigned after declaring it as const). About the export of the new Vue after it and the whole application structure it's just a better way to format code and your application structure. For more information about that you can refer to the Official Vuex Guide https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html ;)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and validate the answer if it's solved your problem. In further It will may help more people in the future !